# Remove rows from uni-dimensional data.frame and retain it as a data.frame

Tags: r

For implementation reason in some cases I have a data.frame that only contains one colum

```
df=as.data.frame(alpha=1:15)
```

If I now use

```
df[-1, ]
```

it returns a vector, but I would like to keep it as a data.frame.
Any suggestions?

PS: The name of the column contains information and I must therefore keep it.

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(df[-1,])`

Comment: @zx8754 removes the header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
df[-1, , drop=FALSE]
```

Does this work for you?